# How to convert an int String id from within an ArrayList to a usable string?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, fragment

I have scoured through many similar questions but I am unable to find the answer I am looking for. I am pretty much self taught so I apologize for the question. Basically I am trying to access the string id within my array and convert it to a readable string so I can send it to google maps so that the user may navigate there. This is the closest I have gotten.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FoodFragment extends Fragment {

    public FoodFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

        final ArrayList<Location> places = new ArrayList<>();
        places.add(new Location(R.string.food1, R.string.desc1, R.drawable.tapass));
        places.add(new Location(R.string.food2, R.string.desc2, R.drawable.baguette));
        places.add(new Location(R.string.food3, R.string.desc3, R.drawable.sushi));
        places.add(new Location(R.string.food4, R.string.desc4, R.drawable.burger));
        places.add(new Location(R.string.food5, R.string.desc5, R.drawable.meat));
        places.add(new Location(R.string.food6, R.string.desc6, R.drawable.pizza));

        final Location here = places.get(0);
        final int address = here.getName();

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), places);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

getName is from my Location class. I realize it is returning an int (so that I can put the string id from string.xml into the array) but how do I get it to return the actual string value?

```
public class Location {

    private int mName;
    private int mDescription;
    private int mImage;


    public Location (int name, int description, int image){
        mName = name;
        mDescription = description;
        mImage = image;
    }

    public int getName(){
        return mName;
    }

    public int getDescription(){
        return mDescription;
    }

    public int getImage(){
        return mImage;
    }
}
```

Again I apologize for noob question and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change you Location class to looks like this

```
public class Location {

    private int mName;
    private int mDescription;
    private int mImage;
    private Context mContext;


    public Location (int name, int description, int image, Context context){
        mName = name;
        mDescription = description;
        mImage = image;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mContext.getString(mName)
    }

    public int getDescription(){
        return mDescription;
    }

    public int getImage(){
        return mImage;
    }
}
```

then you can create Location instance like this

```
places.add(new Location(R.string.food1, R.string.desc1, R.drawable.tapass, getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `address` is resource `id` of `string.xml`
You can access value of `address` id using

```
 String value = getString(address);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much. I'm too new to +1 but I will come back when I have enough rep.